# Fairy chess "leaper" movement patterns

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, chess

A [leaper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece#Leapers) is a category of fairy chess piece which moves by "jumping."  A normal knight is a (1,2)-leaper, meaning each move involves moving a distance of 1 square in an orthogonal direction and 2 squares in the perpendicular direction.

```
.o.o.
o...o
..N..
o...o
.o.o.
```

There are many different leapers. The (1,3)-leaper is called the Long Knight, or Camel.  Its move pattern looks like this:

```
..o.o..
.......
o.....o
...L...
o.....o
.......
..o.o..
```

There's also the (2,2) Alfil...

```
o...o
.....
..A..
.....
o...o
```

...and even the (0,1) Wazir.

```
.o.
oWo
.o.
```

### Challenge

Given a pair of numbers as input, output the corresponding movement diagram.  You may write a program or function, with input provided via STDIN/command-line or as an argument, and output provide by STDOUT or the return value. This is **code-golf**.

**Input**

Input will be a comma-separated list of two integers and an uppercase letter.  The two integers will be in the range `0-7` (inclusive) and in non-decreasing order. Trailing newline optional for input and output.

Here are the inputs for the above four examples:

```
1,2,N
1,3,L
2,2,A
0,1,W
```

**Output**

Output will be a square-shaped multiline string.  The capital letter will be placed in the center to represent the current location of the piece.  The movement locations will be represented by either 4 or 8 lowercase `o`s.  All other spaces in the square will be filled with periods.

If the movement pattern is `0,0`, output just the capital letter.

As a hint, if the second integer (the larger one) has value N, then the square will always have side length 2N+1.  The `o`s will always be on the perimeter of the square.

### Additional Testcases

```
1,1,F

o.o
.F.
o.o

5,7,Q

..o.........o..
...............
o.............o
...............
...............
...............
...............
.......Q.......
...............
...............
...............
...............
o.............o
...............
..o.........o..


0,0,J

J
```

Comment: Why is the camel testcase letter a 'L'? I know out doesn't matter but it might be helpful to change out to a 'C'.

Comment: @RikerW My choice wasn't completely arbitrary, that's its "standardized" letter.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense.

Comment: For a function, are 3 arguments ok or do you want a single string argument comma separated?

Comment: @PhiNotPi where do you get the “standard” code. L is more commonly Bishop in German - and two letter codes are used for the fairy pieces

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby,107

```
->a,b,n{(-b..b).map{|i|s='..'*b+?.
i%b==0&&(i==0?s[b]=n :s[b+a]=s[b-a]=?o)
i.abs==a&&s[0]=s[-1]=?o
puts s}}
```

Ungolfed in test program

```
f=->a,b,n{
  (-b..b).map{|i|                           #iterate from -i to i (lines of grit)
    s='..'*b+?.                             #make a string of 2n+1 .'s
    i%b==0&&(i==0?s[b]=n :s[b+a]=s[b-a]=?o) #if i%b=0 plot the centre character (if i=0) or the o's on the top and bottom rows
    i.abs==a&&s[0]=s[-1]=?o                 #if i.abs=a plot the o's in left and right columns
    puts s                                  #having substituted the .'s with o and centre as necessary, output the current line
  }
}

a=gets.to_i
b=gets.to_i
n=gets.chop
f[a,b,n]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 40 bytes

```
JASv<2zFZK+rH_1SHFY,LZKp?qJSY\o?sY\.ez)k
```

I'm learning Pyth! [Try it out](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=JASv%3C2zFZK%2BrH_1SHFY%2CLZKp%3FqJSY%5Co%3FsY%5C.ez%29k&input=7%2C5%2CQ&debug=0).

### Explanation

```
J             J =
 A                (G, H) =
  S                        sorted(
   v<2z                           eval(input[:-2]))

FZK+rH_1SH    for Z in K = [H, H-1, ..., 0] + [1, 2, ..., H]:
  FY,LZK          for Y in [(Z, k) for k in K]:
    p                 print the following value without newline:
     ?qJSY\o              if J = sorted(Y): 'o'
       ?sY\.              if sum(Y) != 0:   '.'
         ez               else:             input[-1]
  )               end for
k                 print newline
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>163</s> <s>161</s> 145 bytes

```
(x,y,c,m=a=>`\n`+a.slice(1).reverse().join``+a.join``,a=Array(y+1).fill`.`,q=a.map(_=>[...a]))=>m(q.map(m,q[x][y]=q[y][x]='o',q[0][0]=c)).slice(2)
```

Where `\n` is the literal new line character. Works by generating the bottom right quadrant and mirroring it along both axes.

Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @edc65.

(I got here via a duplicate question which allowed an array result which would have been 19 bytes shorter, but didn't guarantee nondecreasing order, which wasted 8 bytes.)

Comment: You can save 3 bytes using a template string with no brackets for `fill` and a literal newline

Comment: @edc65 I'd already tried to adjust for the literal newline (I always write "Where `\n` is the literal new line character" when I do that) but thanks for the other tip.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6) 144 <s>150</s>

```js
(a,b,c,g=Array(b-~b).fill`.`)=>(g=g.map(x=>[...g])).map(x=>x.join``,[b-a,b+a].map(t=>g[t][0]=g[0][t]=g[t][2*b]=g[2*b][t]='o'),g[b][b]=c).join`
`
```

**Less golfed**

```js
(a,b,c)=> {
  var g=Array(b*2+1).fill('.');
  g=g.map(x=>[...g]);
  var q=(t)=>
    g[t][0] =
    g[0][t] =
    g[t][2*b] =
    g[2*b][t] = 'o';
  q(b+a);
  q(b-a);
  g[b][b] = c;
  return g.map(x=> x.join('')).join('\n')
}
```

**Test**

```js
f=(a,b,c,g=Array(b-~b).fill`.`)=>(g=g.map(x=>[...g])).map(x=>x.join``,[b-a,b+a].map(t=>g[t][0]=g[0][t]=g[t][2*b]=g[2*b][t]='o'),g[b][b]=c).join`
`

console.log=x=>O.textContent+=x+'\n'

t=`1,2,N
1,3,L
2,2,A
0,1,W
1,1,F
5,7,Q`.split`\n`
.forEach(t=>([x,y,z]=t.split`,`, console.log(t+'\n'+f(+x,+y,z)+'\n')))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```