# Help Sam understand chess

Tags: code-golf, chess

For this challenge, you will be writing a program or function which outputs (or prints) (in a reasonable format, i.e single string or an array of lines) a chess board which indicates all the possible moves of a piece given an empty board.

---

There are 5 chess pieces (for this challenge a pawn may be ignored):

- **B**ishop (Moves diagonally any number of squares)
- **R**ook (Moves orthogonally any number of squares)
- **Q**ueen (Moves diagonally or orthogonally any number of squares)
- K**N**ight (Moves in an L shape, i.e. two in one dimension, and one in the other)
- **K**ing (Moves one step orthogonally or diagonally)

---

Your submission will take in three inputs: the row of the chess piece, the column of the chess piece, and the type of piece (as a character or integer).

Say we call drawBoard(4,4,'N') for the Knight using 0-indexing, the output will be as follows:

```
........
........
...M.M..
..M...M.
....N...
..M...M.
...M.M..
........
```

where the '.' and 'M' can be replaced accordingly with printable ascii characters of your choice.

Sample outputs as follows for other piece types. (Note all of these are called with input of 4,4 and are 0-indexed).

King:

```
........
........
........
...mmm..
...mKm..
...mmm..
........
........
```

Rook:

```
....m...
....m...
....m...
....m...
mmmmRmmm
....m...
....m...
....m...
```

---

Sam does not mind 1-based indexing, or even indexing following chess algebraic notation. However, your code must be as small as possible so Sam has enough space to think about his chess with the code next to him.

---

Sam has also realized that outputs will be accepted regardless of trailing or preceding whitespace (before and after input and each line)

Comment: I would advise either changing the `o`s to `.`s, or changing them to spaces and adding a border. It's kinda unreadable at the moment.

Comment: related http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69014/fairy-chess-leaper-movement-patterns

Comment: @El'endiaStarman done

Comment: Are spaces to the right of the output ok?

Comment: sure, may I asky why? @LevelRiverSt

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala I was thinking of using modular aritmetic for the bishops moves but decided against it. For example, in a 64 character string representation of a board (ignoring newlines) with a bishop standing at x=4, y=0, all the squares it can move to have either x%9=4 or x%7=4. Unfortunately this also allows for the bishop to wrap around if he walks of the board, which is not permitted in chess. A solution is to pad the end of each line to, say 16, with spaces (and a newline) and increase to x%15 and x%17 so that no wrapping occurs in the region of interest. But I abandoned the idea.

Comment: related http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/89647/chess-conversion#89647

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ruby, 125

anonymous function, prints to stdout.

RevB: golfed, but a bug fix brought it back to the same length as before.

```
->x,y,z{72.times{|i|v=y-i/9;u=x-i%=9
e=u*u+v*v
$><<(i<8?e<1?z:[r=0==v*u,b=u*u==v*v,b|r,3>e,5==e]["RBQKN"=~/#{z}/]??*:?.:$/)}}
```

Prints each of the 64 squares + 8 newlines = 72 characters individually.
Relies on e, the square of the Euclidean distance between the current square and the given coordinates for checking king moves and knight moves (and also for printing the piece value z when the Euclidean distance is zero.)

**Ungolfed in test program**

```
f=->x,y,z{                         #x,y,character
  72.times{|i|                     #8 rows of (8 chars + newline) = 72 chars
    v=y-i/9;                       #vertical diff between y coord and current square
    u=x-i%=9                       #horizontal diff between x coord and current square. note i%=8
    e=u*u+v*v                      #square of euclidean distance
    $><<(                          #$> is stdout. send to it....
      i<8?                         #if not the newline column,
        e<1?z:                       #if the euclidean distance is 0, print the symbol for the piece, else
        [r=0==v*u,                   #TRUE if v or u is 0 (rook)
        b=u*u==v*v,                  #TRUE if abs(u)==abs(v) (bishop)
        b|r,                         #TRUE if either of the above are true (queen)
        3>e,                         #TRUE if e == 1 or 2 (king)
        5==e                         #TRUE if e == 5 (knight)
        ]["RBQKN"=~/#{z}/]??*:?.:    #select value from array corresponding to piece and print * or . accordingly
      $/                           #if newline column, print a newline
    )
  }
}

x=gets.to_i
y=gets.to_i
z=gets.chomp
f[x,y,z]
```

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>137</s> 130 bytes

```js
f=
(x,y,p)=>`${1e8}`.repeat(8).replace(/./g,c=>+c?(i=x*x--,z=y,`
`):i+(j=z*z--)?`.*`[+!{K:i+j>3,N:i+j-5,R:i*j,B:b=i-j,Q:b*i*j}[p]]:p)
;
```

```html
<div onchange=if(+x.value&&+y.value&&p.value)o.textContent=f(x.value,y.value,p.value)><input id=x type=number placeholder=X><input id=y type=number placeholder=Y><select id=p><option value=>Piece<option value=B>Bishop<option value=K>King<option value=N>Knight<option value=Q>Queen<option value=R>Rook</select><div><pre id=o></pre>
```

Note: Outputs one leading newline.

Explanation: Builds and scans though the string `100000000100000000100000000100000000100000000100000000100000000100000000`. Each `1` indicates a new line where the relative coordinate `x` is decremented and the relative coordinate `z` is reset. Each `0` indicates a new square where the relative coordinate `z` is decremented. (`y` is reserved to reset `z`.) Then uses the fact that many of the moves can be categorised by the squares `i` and `j` of the relative coordinates (before they were decremented):

- (initial square) `i + j == 0`
- B: `i == j`
- K: `i + j < 3`
- N: `i + j == 5`
- Q: `i == j || !i || !j`
- R: `!i || !j`

Because `-` is shorter than `==` it's golfier to compute the negation and invert it later. (This lets me use the cute `'.*'[]` expression although it's actually the same length as a boring `?:` expression.) `*` is also golfier than `&&`.

Comment: How about using 0 and 1 as we can replace . and M with other ASCII characters?

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto Sorry, I'm not following you; have you commented on the wrong answer or something?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant the `'.*'` part could be omitted and output 0 and 1 in place of `.` and `*`

Comment: @ShieruAsakoto Thanks, I see what you meant now, but I think I probably chose those characters to make the output look nice and I can't see myself switching even though it would save 6 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

### Java 8 lambda, <s>473</s> <s>435</s> 289 characters

Looks like this:

```
(R,C,f)->{String b="";for(int r=0,c,d,D;r<8;r++){for(c=0;c<8;c++){d=R-r<0?r-R:R-r;D=C-c<0?c-C:C-c;b+=R==r&&C==c?f:((f=='R'||f=='Q')&&(R==r||C==c))||((f=='B'||f=='Q')&&d==D)||(f=='K'&&((R==r&&D==1||C==c&&d==1)||(d==D&&d==1)))||(f=='N'&&(d==2&&D==1||d==1&&D==2))?"M":".";}b+="\n";}return b;}
```

Or ungolfed into a class:

```
public class Q89429 {

    static String chessMoves(int row, int column, char figure) {
        String board = "";

        for (int r = 0, c, deltaRow, deltaColumn; r < 8; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
                deltaRow = row - r < 0 ? r - row : row - r;
                deltaColumn = column - c < 0 ? c - column : column - c;
                board += row == r && column == c ?
                        figure :
                        ((figure == 'R' || figure == 'Q') && (row == r || column == c))
                        || ((figure == 'B' || figure == 'Q') && deltaRow == deltaColumn)
                        || (figure == 'K' && (
                                (row == r && deltaColumn == 1 || column == c && deltaRow == 1)
                                || (deltaRow == deltaColumn && deltaRow == 1)))
                        || (figure == 'N' && (deltaRow == 2 && deltaColumn == 1 || deltaRow == 1 && deltaColumn == 2))
                        ? "M" : ".";
            }
            board += "\n";
        }

        return board;
    }
}
```

This is a [TriFunction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19649473/3764634). It returns the chess field as a printable String. <s>I wanted to use streams, and it looks quite good. It's like a 2D iteration, may be shorter without the streams.</s> *Switched to classic loops and saved a lot!*

<s>It can definitely be shortened by using a ternary, I will do that now.</s>

**Updates**

Saved 38 characters by using a ternary.

Saved 146 characters by using good old loops. We should all abandon streams ;)

Comment: for loops may be shorter

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala I also thought about that. Currently working on the ternary. After that I will switch to loops, just needed some practice in using streams :D

Comment: :D (11 more characters)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 209 Bytes

```
->v,a,b{R=->x,y{x==a||y==b};B=->x,y{x-y==a-b||a-x==y-b};Q=->x,y{R.(x,y)||B.(x,y)};K=->x,y{((x-a).i+y-b).abs<2};N=->x,y{((a-x)*(b-y)).abs==2};(r=(0..7)).map{|x|r.map{|y|[x,y]==[a,b]?v: eval(v+".(x,y)??x:?o")}}}
```

This is a lambda that makes use of other lambdas, defined inside.

Answer (score 2):

## x86 machine code, <s>114</s> 103 bytes

Input:

- AL - ASCII piece type (N/B/R/Q/K)
- BP - 0x88 index
- DI - Buffer

Output:

- DI - Last character + 1

Assembly source code:

```
    pusha
    mov di, offset disp_db - 3
    mov cx, 8
    mov bx, cx
    repne scasb
    mov dx, di
    sub dx, offset disp_db - 1
    pop si
    mov di, si

init_loop:
    mov ax, '.'
    mov cl, 8
    rep stosb
    mov al, 9
    mov cl, 7
    rep stosb
    inc ax
    stosb
    dec bx
    jnz init_loop

init_done:
    push di
    mov di, si

piece_loop:
    mov si, offset moves_knight - 2
    add si, dx
    lodsb
    add si, ax

vec_loop:
    lodsb
    cbw

sign_loop:
    mov bx, bp

dest_loop:
    add bx, ax
    test bl, 088h
    jnz vec_cont
    mov byte ptr [di + bx], '*'
    test dl, dl
    jp dest_loop

vec_cont:
    neg ax
    js sign_loop
    cmp al, 80h
    jnz vec_loop

done:
    popa
    mov [di + bp - 128], al
    ret

disp_db db "NBKRQ"

moves_knight db vec_knight - moves_knight - 1
moves_bishop db vec_bishop - moves_bishop - 1
moves_king   db vec_king   - moves_king   - 1
moves_rook   db vec_rook   - moves_rook   - 1
moves_queen  db vec_king   - moves_queen  - 1

vec_knight db 0Eh, 12h, 1Fh, 21h, 80h
vec_bishop db 0Fh, 11h, 80h
vec_king   db 0Fh, 11h
vec_rook   db 01h, 10h, 80h
```